# How do I group by List<int> in a Dictionary<string, List<int>> where the lists are identical?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to take a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` and then create groups for all duplicate Lists in the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> AllLists = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()
{
    {"one", new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}},
    {"two", new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}},
    {"three", new List<int>() {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
};

var ListGroups = AllLists.GroupBy(p => p.Value);
```

This should group the dictionary indexes with matching lists into their own groups, but it just creates a group for every index in the dictionary. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: because the compiler doesn't know how to compare your lists.

Comment: So, what can I do to fix it? @Selman22

Comment: @DavidMyers, so you want to remove duplicate entries?

Comment: Actually, I'd just like to get it sorted into groups. I'm later merging all of the duplicate lists, but that part is working fine so far. @AmitJoki

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's going to use a reference comparison on your `List<int>` objects. Since both `List<int>` containing `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` are separately instantiated, they will have distinct references.

Try the following, for example:

```
var ListGroups = AllLists.GroupBy(p => string.Join(",", p.Value));
```

This will group by `string` representations of your lists.  Note that this is probably *not* what you want to do and is purely demonstrative.

You can use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `GroupBy` method to pass in a custom `IEqualityComparer<List<int>>` that actually looks at the contents of the lists using `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`.

Here's the `IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>`:

```
class IEnumerableEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
    {
        return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(a, b);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int shift = 0;
        int result = 1;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            int hash = item != null ? item.GetHashCode() : 17;
            result ^= (hash << shift)
                    | (hash >> (32 - shift))
                    & (1 << shift - 1);
            shift = (shift + 1) % 32;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And here's how you use it:

```
var ListGroups = AllLists.GroupBy(p => p.Value,
    new IEnumerableEqualityComparer<int>());
```

Note that because `IEqualityComparer<T>` is contravariant in `T` you can use the above one for `List<int>` because that implements `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: I was worried that it was comparing the references... I tried this, and I also tried p.Value.ToString(), but to no avail. As long as I can get it to separate into the separate groups, it will definitely be useful.

Comment: @DavidMyers "I tried this." Are you sure? Using `string.Join(",", p.Value)` as your key will work.

Comment: This answer leaves off the most difficult part, namely how to properly hash a sequence of items.

Comment: Your hash function throws on null items in the sequence, other than that, it's fine.